# Yup allow more than 0 decimal value

Tags: reactjs, validation, yup

I want to allow number which should be more than 0 with decimal number

I tried

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  amount: yup.number().min(0),
});
```

But, it allow 0 value which I don't want. So, I tried

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
    amount: yup.number().min(0.1),
});
```

But, it not allow 0.001 or 0.0002

How can change which allow more than 0 decimal value. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to use Regex instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `yup.number.positive()` instead `min(0)`

https://github.com/jquense/yup#numberpositivemessage-string--function-schema

Comment: But, it allow 0 value

Comment: Oh you can try `yup.number.moreThan(0)`

Comment: I am using 0.21.3

Comment: Please update to the lastest version 0.32.9